# Android layout issue--ListView not displaying

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

I am having trouble getting a `ListView` to display anything in my application.  I am sure the `ListView`'s adapter is getting set correctly (and I can read out the data in it using Log.d to confirm), so I'm guessing the issue is in the XML layout.  I have an autocomplete box and the button on the top of the screen, with the `ListView` underneath.  Both the `AutoComplete` and the `Button` display fine and work correctly, however I see nothing whatsoever for the `ListView`.

The only thing I can think of at the moment is that I could be doing something weird with the `LinearLayouts` that prevent the `ListView` from displaying, or something similar.  I've been reading all the docs I can on Android layouts, but haven't run across anything that looks like it can help yet...  Can someone help me figure out why the ListView is not being displayed at all?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" android:weightSum="1">
        <com.myapp.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete_itemname"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.90"/>
            <Button android:text="Locate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button_item_list_located_item"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Button>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/selected_items_listview"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Hierarchy Viewer output]

Comment: look at the graphical layout of your xml file in eclipse. If its right, then look at your activity code in which you are using this xml file. This xml works fine in my project.

Comment: listview typing error in layout_height = wrap_content

Comment: thanks, fixed the typo but still no dice.

Comment: check my answer,i have tested it and works fine..tell me if any problem occur

Comment: Turned out to be a constructor issue, despite no warnings/errors being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `layout_height` of your wrapping root `LinearLayout` to `"fill_parent"` instead of `"match_parent"`

Comment: Have you tried looking it up in the heirarchy viewer? Might get some idea from there.

Comment: I haven't used the hierarchy viewer before, but just loaded it and don't see the ListView anywhere.

Comment: Do you see ListView in the hierarchy tree (on the left part of the hierarchy viewer)?

Comment: Could you save your view as a png and post it here?

Comment: I see that your ListView is missing. Don't know why that would happen. Try removing the `android:text` attribute from your `ListView`. I don't think it is the right way to specify empty messages.

Comment: Well, I'm running out of ideas. One last try. Try changing the height of your inner `LinearLayout` to 0 instead of `wrap_content`. See the results in hierarchy viewer now.

Comment: Still nothing :(  Thanks for the assistance though!!

Comment: Hey, I see you have accepted my answer. How did you solve it?

Comment: fill_parent is just the deprecated version of the match_parent. Both do the same thing for the layout, making view's height filling the parent view height

Answer (score 2):

Is the inner `LinearLayout` neccessary for your application?

If not, remove the

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
```

statement in the inner linear layout and try.

Answer (score -3):

Your question is not specific, did you declare an Array Adapter in your .java file?

If you didn't, I suggest you use:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private ListView lv1;
private String lv_arr[] =
{ "Android", "iPhone", "BlackBerry", "me", "J2ME", "Listview", "ArrayAdapter", "ListItem", "Us", "UK", "India" };
ListView lst;

ArrayAdapter<String> arrad;

@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

 arrad =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr);
 lv1.setAdapter(arrad);

// By using setTextFilterEnabled method in listview we can filter the listview items.
```